# How to capture a form element and use dynamically in the post url?

Tags: php, javascript, html

I'm trying to build a form which submits a URL which contains a lon/lat that has been passed over from Google Maps.  I have managed to get it so the lon/lat is passed into input fields in the form, how would I go about using these values dynamically in the post URL, i.e.:

```
action="search.asp?[lon][lat]
```

Comment: I should add it's sat on a PHP page, not an asp page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using javascript you can change the action attribute of the form. So, create a form..

```
<form name="myForm">
  <input type="hidden" name="lon" value="123" />
  <input type="hidden" name="lat" value="321" />
  ...
  <button onclick="setAction();">Submit</button>
</form>
```

Then in the head of the page add the setAction function..

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  function setAction()
  {
    var lon = document.myForm.lon.value;
    var lat = document.myForm.lat.value;

    document.myForm.action = "search.php?["+lat+"]["+lon+"]"';
    document.myForm.submit();
  }
</script>
```

Hope this helps, it's how I have done this in the past!

Comment: thanks very much - that makes sense, I'm going to have a look at working that in.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to get the values from the form into the URL, set the [`method` attribute](http://www.w3schools.com/TAGS/att_form_method.asp) to `get`:

```
<form method="search.asp" action="get">
```

. This will put the values of the `lon` and `lat` fields of the form in the URL. Example:

```
search.asp?lat=[lat value]&lon=[lon value]
```

For more information, read [this page](http://www.cs.tut.fi/~jkorpela/forms/methods.html). Excerpt:

> If the processing of a form is
>   idempotent (i.e. it has no lasting
>   observable effect on the state of the
>   world), then the form method should be
>   GET. Many database searches have no
>   visible side-effects and make ideal
>   applications of query forms.

Answer (score 0):

Try using:

```
<form action="search.php" method="get">
 <input type="hidden" name="lon" value="<?php echo $lon_fromGoogleMaps; ?>" />
 <input type="hidden" name="lat" value="<?php echo $lat_fromGoogleMaps; ?>" />
 <!-- The Rest of your Form... -->
 <input type="submit" value="Submit!" />
</form>
```

Or if you want to use the form as post:

```
<form action="search.php?lon=<?php echo $lon_fromGoogleMaps; ?>&amp;lat=<?php echo $lat_fromGoogleMaps; ?>" method="post">
 <!-- The Rest of your Form... -->
 <input type="submit" value="Submit!" />
</form>
```

I see you tagged this as Javascript as well, and as Google Maps relies heavily on Javascript, you may have the Lon and the Lat passed as Javascript variables...

```
<script type="text/javascript">
 // Obviously, execute this code after the DOM has loaded...
 var formAction = document.searchForm.action;
 formAction = formAction + '?lon=' + lon_fromGoogleMaps + '&amp;lat=' + lat_fromGoogleMaps;
 document.searchForm.action = formAction;
</script>
<form action="search.php" method="post" name="searchForm">
 <!-- The Rest of your Form... -->
 <input type="submit" value="Submit!" />
</form>
```